# My Windows Update will not open.

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I get an error message: Windows cannot currently check for updates because the service is not running. You may need to restart your computer. I have gone through this process 10 times but get the same message. I'm using Vista Home.
THanks  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. Click Start, type services.msc, find Windows Updates or Automatic Updates &  make sure the service is set to automatic start
2. It'd probably be good to run the [Windows Update Troubleshooter tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/windows-update-issues/en-us)
3. Click Start, type `cmd`, right-click cmd & `Run as administratr`, in this black window type `sfc /scannow`. This is Windows File Checker & it checks the integrity of the core files Windows uses
4. Try updates in Safe Mode: repeatly (every 1-2sec) hit F8 while PC it powering-on, it will produce a menu (at this point stop hitting F8), & select the Safe Mode entry & hit Enter
5. Still not working? [Drastic measures need to be taken: try a System Restore or in-place upgrade of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949358)

Comment: Tried both procedures but still no solution. Several days ago I allowed a so called tech work on my PC, remotely, to attempt to rectify a printer problem I had. Still have that problem too, and I am certain he caused the problem with my Windows Update. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, lots of scams lately. I'd suggest running an antivirus on your PC to make sure they didn't infect you or cause other harm. It probably also wouldn't be a bad idea to do a backup now just in case. I expanded my answer with some other ideas. I had similar issues on two work Win7 PC's lately & I had to do option 5, an in-place upgrade (basically re-installs windows keeping apps installed). Please accept my answer (click checkmark) if it solves your issue or no one else assists you